# How to read the json array using dynamic array name and key pair in java

Tags: java, json

```
{
"name1": [
    "value1"
],
"name2": [
    "value1",
    "value2",
    "value3",
    "value4",
    "value5",

],
"name3": [
    "value1"
]
}
```

new to JSON.Please help me to read this name and value in this file

Answer (score -1):

You need to supply the key of each array like `name1` , `name2`, `name3` etc. So it is better to set a limit for the names like 10. Following code will parse the json file as you expected

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map=new HashMap<>();
    int TOTAL_NAMES=10;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(json);
        for(int k=0; k<TOTAL_NAMES-1; k++) {
            String name="name"+k;
            JSONArray jsonValueArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray(name);
            ArrayList<String> valueList=new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonValueArray1.length(); i++) {
                valueList.add(jsonValueArray1.getString(i));
            }
            map.put(name, valueList);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.but the names are dynamic so i should use some position values to retrieve the name and value as well